# How to click on JLabel, edit with JTextField and exit changing Jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am trying to create a GUI and in that GUI I have different JLabels with a value. I want to be able to click on a JLabel to edit it in my JTextfield (only have 1) and after I press enter it should leave Editing the JLabel. At the moment if I try to edit a JLabel it will change but when I click on the next one the old one will also still change.

This is my code:

```
public class GUI {
JFrame frame;
int n1=1;
int n2=1;
int n3=1;
GUI(){
    frame=new JFrame();//creating instance of JFrame
    JLabel l1=new JLabel(Integer.toString(n1));
    JLabel l2=new JLabel(Integer.toString(n2));
    JLabel l3=new JLabel(Integer.toString(n3));
    JTextField t=new JTextField();

    l1.setBounds(40,50,100, 40);
    l2.setBounds(40,100,100, 40);
    l3.setBounds(40,150,100, 40);
    t.setBounds(20,200,100, 40);

    frame.add(l1);
    frame.add(l2);
    frame.add(l3);
    frame.add(t);


    l1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    l1.setText(t.getText());
                    n1=parseInt(t.getText());
                }
            });
        }
    });

    l2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    l2.setText(t.getText());
                    n2=parseInt(t.getText());
                }
            });
        }
    });



    frame.setSize(400,500);//400 width and 500 height
    frame.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers
    frame.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This leaves me asking the question of, why not simply toggle a borderless/transparent `JTextField` between non-editable and editable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't add action listeners for each click. Clicking on a label should record the state of your UI -- that that label is now being edited, and set up the value in the `JTextField`. Then enter should transfer the value to the `JLabel` which was recorded as selected.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GUI {
    JLabel currentEditLabel = null;
    JFrame frame;
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n3 = 1;

    GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();//creating instance of JFrame
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n1));
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n2));
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n3));
        JTextField t = new JTextField();

        l1.setBounds(40, 50, 100, 40);
        l2.setBounds(40, 100, 100, 40);
        l3.setBounds(40, 150, 100, 40);
        t.setBounds(20, 200, 100, 40);

        frame.add(l1);
        frame.add(l2);
        frame.add(l3);
        frame.add(t);

        t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (currentEditLabel != null) {
                    currentEditLabel.setText(t.getText());
                    currentEditLabel = null;
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(l1, t);
        addMouseListener(l2, t);
        addMouseListener(l3, t);

        frame.setSize(400, 500);//400 width and 500 height
        frame.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers
        frame.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible
    }

    private void addMouseListener(JLabel label, JTextField t) {
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                currentEditLabel = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
                t.setText(currentEditLabel.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
}
```

Figuring out how to set n1, n2, ... is left as an exercise, as is how to indicate in the UI that no label is selected (hint: should you allow input in the `JTextField` when no label has been selected?)

As @kleopatra says, using no layout manager is not good practice, as if your panel is resized (perhaps your program will be run on a mobile device, for instance) your components may become hidden, See [this discussion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

Here's your code using `GridLayout`, a simple layout manager.

Points to note:

- I've removed the absolute positioning and sizing of the components and the frame.
- The frame is now resizable, so you can see what the layout manager does as the size changes.
- The `JFrame` is `pack`ed before displaying it.

To get a layout which does exactly what you want you can look at `GridBagLayout`, and also think about nesting containers with simple layout managers.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GUI {
    JLabel currentEditLabel = null;
    JFrame frame;
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 1;
    int n3 = 1;

    GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n1));
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n2));
        JLabel l3 = new JLabel(Integer.toString(n3));
        JTextField t = new JTextField();
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(4, 1, 10, 10);
        frame.setLayout(layout);
        frame.add(l1);
        frame.add(l2);
        frame.add(l3);
        frame.add(t);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (currentEditLabel != null) {
                    currentEditLabel.setText(t.getText());
                    currentEditLabel = null;
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(l1, t);
        addMouseListener(l2, t);
        addMouseListener(l3, t);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible
    }

    private void addMouseListener(JLabel label, JTextField t) {
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                currentEditLabel = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
                t.setText(currentEditLabel.getText());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is exactly what I wanted! Also thanks for the hint I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but do you maybe have a hint to set n1, n2?

Comment: You'll need to use a similar approach, where the `mouseClicked` methods sets a reference to an object which contains the int. You could use an `int[]` and set the index to update, or you could use `AtomicInteger` and have a field which you update to point to the relevant `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: __do not__ use null layout which here means __not__ propagating errors in the question